# Does the first derivative of a function change its sign at local extremum points?

Tags: calculus

Does the first derivative of a function change its sign at local extremum points? If yes how to prove it. Also the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}, x > 0$$ and $$f(x)=3x^2, x \leq 0$$ has a minimum at $x=0$, but the first derivative doesn't change its sign at $x=0$.

Comment: The function $f$ you defined isn't even continuous at $0$, let alone being differentiable at $0$, so in your example, it doesn't really make sense to talk about the first derivative changing sign (because $f'(0)$ doesn't even exist)

Comment: For $f(x) = 3x^2$, limiting the domain to $x \leq 0$ makes the function a global min at $x = 0$. The first derivative test defines local extrema as changes in sign.

Comment: But if we consider the function $$f(x)=(2-sin(\frac{1}{x}))|x|$$ for $x$ not equal to $0$ and $$f(x)=0$$ for $x=0$

Comment: Also does the first derivative changes it's sign at local extremum and if it does hot to prove it

Comment: See the discussion of the [First Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#First_derivative_test).

Comment: Suppose $f(x)$ is has a local extremum at $x = p$. Then this has to be consistent with the FTC: $f(p+x) = f(p) + \int_{p}^{p+x}f'(t) dt$